# Bootstrap radio buttons in Yesod: how to get value?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, yesod

I try to get value of radio button from Bootstrap value in Yesod. So this is my inline-radio:

```
<form .form-horizontal
    ...
    <label .radio-inline>
        <input type=radio
               name=gender
               checked>_{MsgMale}
    <label .radio-inline>
        <input type=radio
               name=gender>_{MsgFemale}
```

But I don't understand how can I get value of `gender`. I try it:

```
data NewPatient = NewPatient { lastName       
                             , firstName :: Text
                             , gender    :: Bool
                             } deriving Show

...

newPatient <- runInputPost $ 
              NewPatient <$> ireq textField "patientLastName"
                         <*> ireq textField "patientFirstName"
                         <*> ireq boolField "patientGender"
```

but `gender` is always `True`.

I've tried to use `value` attribute for `input`, but in this case I got an error `Invalid boolean`.

I've read this in [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.4.4/docs/Yesod-Form-Fields.html#v:boolField):

```
If this field is required, the first radio button is labeled "Yes" and the second "No".
```

But I don't understand it. What is it mean "labeled" in this case?

Please help me.

Comment: labeled means "has a small description for user beside the radio button"

Comment: Ok, but how can I extract a value of male/female buttons?

Comment: I think using a boolean value for gender is a little weird. I would probably use `selectFieldList` or `radioFieldList` with `data Gender = Male | Female` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
<form .form-horizontal
    ...
    <label .radio-inline>
        <input type=radio
               name=gender
               value=on                 <<< exactly `on` 
               checked>_{MsgMale}
    <label .radio-inline>
        <input type=radio
               value=no                 <<< exactly `no`
               name=gender>_{MsgFemale}
```

In this case I have `True` if user checked on first button (Male), and `False` if he checked second button (Female).